# compare function in inbuilt qsort function

Tags: c, sorting, qsort

I am trying to use the inbuilt qsort function in C to sort a structure

```
typedef struct abc{
  long long int fir;
  long long int sec;
}abc;
```

In the compare function I used the below code so that if the variable "fir" is same between any two elements in the array of structure abc then the sorting condition will depend on the variable "sec".

```
long long int cmp(const abc*  e1, const abc* e2)
{
if(e1->fir==e2->fir)
       return e1->sec-e2->sec;
else
    return e1->fir-e2->fir;
}
```

The code doesn't seem to work properly.
What is the correct method to do it?

Comment: Ok.  What's the question here?

Comment: How does it not work? Can you post the calling code, or a complete small program?

Comment: Making your comparison function match the signature specified by qsort would be a good start. It should be int (*compar)(const void *, const void *).  Depending on your platform and how it handles arguments and return values it might not matter; then again it might.

Comment: The problem here is evident from the posted code ... please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long long int cmp(const abc*  e1, const abc* e2)
```

does not have the correct signature for a qsort comparison function, so your program has undefined behavior. You should set your compiler warning flags high, and it will warn you of such things.

Your actual test is fine as long as the subtraction can't overflow, which is probably not a problem for long long. **Edit** The subtraction is not fine here, precisely because the return value of `cmp` must be an `int`. The result of the subtraction `long long`, so if you have large values the result is too big to fit into an `int` and `qsort` is sure to produce the wrong order.

More generally, though, this is more accurate:

```
int cmp(const void* v1, const void* v2)
{
    const struct abc* p1 = v1;
    const struct abc* p2 = v2;

    if (p1->fir < p2->fir)
        return -1;
    else if (p1->fir > p2->fir)
        return 1;
    else
        return p1->sec < p2->sec? -1 : p1->sec > p2->sec? 1 : 0;       
}
```

Comment: I made a quick code to test it  but it doesn't seems to work-:
http://pastebin.com/tM2f7N0P

Comment: @learner The main problem is that the array you are sorting is an array of `abc*` but your cmp routine expects `abc`s ... the arguments to `cmp` *point* to the elements of the array, they aren't elements themselves. Either use an array `abc` or do another dereference in your cmp routine, e.g. `abc* e1 = *(abc**)v1` etc. You're on your own beyond that ... I can't do more in these comments

Answer (score 0):

The built-in qsort you're using probably expects a "lower-than" (operator<) predicate, which is the normal terminology for C++. And yours returns true in both cases as long as the arguments aren't equal.

You have to return true IFF (if and only if) `e1<e2`.

Comment: "The built-in qsort you're using probably expects a "lower-than" (operator<) predicate" -- Wrong. "the normal terminology for C++" -- This is tagged C, not C++.

Comment: @JimBalter You're right, I haven't noticed its C - my apologies. I've upvoted your reply so its first, and I'll let mine stay.. maybe he'll upgrade to c++ sometime :)

Comment: Indeed. I wrote C for 35 years and was on the C language standards committee ... writing in it today is  a serious mistake unless its legacy code. That people are teaching this stuff to beginners is abominable, especially when there are things like http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-001-structure-and-interpretation-of-computer-programs-spring-2005/index.htm available.